# разбивка строки на массив

Tags: javascript

Как из такой `Organization/LimitedCompany/HousingCooperative` строки можно сделать массив такого вида: `['Organization', 'Organization/LimitedCompany', 'Organization/LimitedCompany/HousingCooperative']`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
let str = 'Organization/LimitedCompany/HousingCooperative',
  temp = null,
  result = [];
let data = str.split('/');

data.forEach(function(item, index, array) {
  temp = (temp !== null) ? temp + '/' + item : item;
  result.push(temp);
});

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

Вариант с `reduce`:

```js
let str = 'Organization/LimitedCompany/HousingCooperative';
let data = str.split('/');

let result = data.reduce((acc, item, i) => {
  acc.push((i ? acc[i - 1] + '/' : '') + item);
  return acc;
}, [])

console.log(result)
```

И с `map`:

```js
let str = 'Organization/LimitedCompany/HousingCooperative';
let data = str.split('/');

let result = data.map((item, i, arr) => arr.slice(0, i + 1).join('/'));
console.log(result);
```